# Waiting for async Tasks to complete on Termination

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In below code there are 2 files main.py and pollhz.py. Main initiates PollHz to perform some async tasks. Now if there is a termination requested SIGINT, SIGTERM. I wish it to wait until the async tasks are done. I need bit help in performing it.
Note: It should work on Windows and Unix as I tried add loop.add_signal_handler but its not supported in Windows

main.py

```
def main(config):
 asyncio.run(async_main(config))

async def async_main(config):
 """Pull from HZ Queue and process it"""
 global poll
 setup_signal()
 doc: list[dict] = get_config_dict(config)
 poll = PollHZ(doc)
 await poll.poll_hz()

def handle_termination(signum, frame):
 logger.info(f"Received signal: {signum}. Performing cleanup")
 if poll:
    poll.cleanup(signum, frame)
 sys.exit(0)

def setup_signal():
 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_termination)
 signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_termination)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()


Class PollHz
def perform(self, notify) -> asyncio.Task:
    tasks: list[asyncio.Task] = [None] * len(MANAGER_MAPPING)
    for key, value in self.info.items():
        pos: int = MANAGER_MAPPING.get(key, -1)
        if pos != -1:
            tasks[pos] = asyncio.create_task(self.managers[pos].parse(notify, value))
    non_none_tasks = [task for task in tasks if task is not None]
    return asyncio.gather(*non_none_tasks)

async def poll_hz(self) -> None:
    tokens = MAX_TOKENS
    interval_count = MAX_INTERVAL
    wait_per_interval = WAIT_PER_INTERVAL
    while tokens > 0 and interval_count > 0 and not self.isTerminating:
        if self.hz_client_queue.peek(self.hz_queue_name):
            tokens = tokens - 1
            interval_count = MAX_INTERVAL
            notify = self.hz_client_queue.pull(self.hz_queue_name)
            if notify is not None:
                self.active_tasks.append(await self.perform(notify))
        else:
            interval_count = interval_count - 1
            await asyncio.sleep(wait_per_interval)

        # Perform cleanup to remove completed tasks from the list
        self.active_tasks = [task for task in self.active_tasks if not task.done()]


async def cleanup_async(self):
    self.isTerminating = True
    logger.info(f"isTerminating: {self.isTerminating}")
    await asyncio.gather(*self.active_tasks)

def cleanup(self, signum, frame):
    # code here to wait until all active_tasks are done
```